# How to change the WCF Service Url?

Tags: wcf, iis, hosting

I have a WCF 3.0 service which has been configured with BasicHttpBinding and has been deployed and hosted in IIS.

I can access my service using the below url:

http://mydomain.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/myservice.svc/basic

"basic" at the end of the address is the relative address of the end point and "/subfolder1/subfolder2" is where the myservice.svc file has been physically deployed to:

```
 <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="Company.MyService.Implementation.Contracts.IMyService">
 </endpoint>
```

How to configure the settings so that I can access my service using the below url without specifiying the .svc path:

http://mydomain.com/myService/basic

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not the responsability of your service. You should build "address-less" service and not specify one absolute in the config.

Your question is relevant to web hosting under IIS. There is a huge difference between the physical path (where you deploy) of your service and the virtual path (where client access it).

In your example, you simply need to create a new web application under *http://mydomain.com/* and publish your service. *subfolder1* seems to be a virtual directory of an existing web site. Just create the web app here, with IIS manager.