# How can I change the URL of my WCF Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, .net-core

I have this WCF Service:

```txt
http://localhost:56471/WcfPruebaService.svc
```

And I need it to be:

```txt
http://localhost:56471/ServiciosDePrueba/WcfPruebaService.svc
```

Comment: This seems to give some insight https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679860/6950415

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open app.config and replace the old address with the new one. 
 Or if you want to change it in code (programmatically) you can use the following code:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("***"));
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-a-wcf-contract#edit-appconfig

 [How to programmatically modify WCF app.config endpoint address setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966323/how-to-programmatically-modify-wcf-app-config-endpoint-address-setting)